# Google Analytics to track Adds

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to include Google analytics to track my App's add activity. This is what I should include according to Google's Guide page:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Enable Advertising Features.
t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
```

Everything is fine, but the problem is I don't know where exactly should I include this code, at least is not clear for me.

Comment: add your SplashActivity's  onCreate method